# Opening Workbook from Outlook without read-only mode

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, readonly

I'm trying to open an excel workbook and run a macro from Outlook. Unfortunately everytime I open the workbook it seems to default to read-only mode, meaning that I cannot run the macro I want to.

Here is my code:

```
Sub runPat(client As String)

'Runs a PAT using tool with client as input

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

Dim sourceWB As Workbook
Dim usr As Worksheet
Dim strFile As String

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

With xlApp
    .Visible = True
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

'Source file, will need to be changed if PAT is ever moved
strFile = "C:\Users\albio\Dropbox\Document Creation Program\Portfolio Analysis Tool\Portfolio Analysis tool v1.0.xlsm"  'PAT File path

'Open workbook
Set sourceWB = Workbooks.Open(strFile, , False)

'Run this PAT
sourceWB.Application.Run "buttons.launchButton"

End Sub
```

I've tried various solutions, such as setting IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended=True and using setAttr to vbNormal before opening the file path. For some reason, it always opens in read-only mode and I can't see why?

[EDIT] The workbook normally opens without read-only mode on. It is only when the workbook is opened within my Outlook VbaProject that read-only is enabled.

Comment: @Fleury26 I'm afraid mine doesn't seem to work using that method either, still opens as read-only

Comment: The problem seems to be with Excel with Macros (xlsm). The problem could be with excel's trust issues (Protection from unsafe places)! You can change that by going to Trust Center > Trust Center Settings

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening the workbook directly from excel and it opens in read-only mode that happens because it is not a trusted document. Usually if you click on enable macros it would add it as a trusted document next time onwards. If that doesn't happen that may be because trusted documents have been disabled.

You can enable trusted documents by navigating to the following location in excel

> file > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted
>   Documents

Here you need to uncheck the "Disable Trusted Documents" and maybe even check the "Allow documents on a network to be trusted"

---

If you are trying to open the excel file through a VBA code then you need to change the automation security before opening the workbook. For example

```
application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow
Workbooks.Open abc.xlsm
Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI 'Changes it back to the default value
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. Unfortunately trusted documents was already enabled so couldn't change any settings there. I tried the application.AutomationSecurity method as well and it still opens in read only mode.

Comment: Are you sure? I think you may have made a mistake because if Trusted documents are not disabled (I don't think this makes a difference), this code should work. I checked it on my system right now as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure yeah: `xlApp.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityLow`
    `Set sourceWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile, , , , , , True)`
    `xlApp.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI`

Comment: Change that to `xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile, , , , , , False)` . See if you get a prompt. Plus it is an xlsm file right?

Comment: It is an xlsm file yes. I tried that and it still opens as read-only... No prompt.